# USB to Ethernet (ASIX AX88772B) stopped working after updates

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

After some updates my USB ethernet stopped working. It correctly connects and even some pings pass for a few seconds, but then everything stops. It still works in Windows 8 (I have dual boot) and Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB, but doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.04 Live USB.

Here is relevant part of dmesg:

```
[  243.849944] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  244.047559] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=7e2b
[  244.047572] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  244.047578] usb 1-1: Product: AX88772B
[  244.047583] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[  244.047587] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0049C7
[  245.971324] asix 1-1:1.0 eth0: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet, 9c:**:**:**:**:**
[  245.971419] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[  246.019793] asix 1-1:1.0 eth0: link down
[  247.711932] asix 1-1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x4DE1
```

Here are `uname`, `lsusb`, `ifconfig` and `lshw` outputs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux suor-xps 3.19.0-22-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 16 17:15:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:644d Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b95:7e2b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:**:**:**:**:**  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::****:****:****:****/** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:14403 (14.4 KB)  TX bytes:28244 (28.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2870 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:533721 (533.7 KB)  TX bytes:533721 (533.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:**:**:**:**:**  
          inet addr:192.168.0.107  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::****:****:****:****/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7934 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6153978 (6.1 MB)  TX bytes:1778823 (1.7 MB)

$ lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 24
       serial: c8:**:**:**:**:**
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-22-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:27 memory:d0400000-d0401fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 9c:**:**:**:**:**
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.0.105 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Comment: Disable your wireless network, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ethernet adapter looks OK. But the problem is that you have connected wired and wireless interfaces at the same time. That confuses routing.

If you disable your wireless interface, network should work OK.

Comment: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` did work, while turning wifi in UI did not. So, thanks a lot, but this can't be a solution, it used to work properly.

Comment: This is proper work. When you enable wired network, you need to change default route to this interface. You can set up a udev rule for that or change default routing, etc.

Comment: But it used to do that automatically, still works in 14.04 Live USB. So something is broken.

Comment: This happens for me too, since I installed the newest Kernel from Vivid (Kernel 3.19), with older Kernels (3.16 and lower) it works.

Comment: I've been hooked up to both ethernet and wifi for 2 years across 5 ubuntu releases and never had a problem... until Vivid. Turning off wifi works, but that should not be necessary.  Also, I don't know what a udev rule is, and I shouldn't need to know what that is.  Networking should just work.

Comment: Btw, this issue is captured  here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1436330  and a fix is imminent in Vivid.  It's also fixed in Wily.